# Is Doctrine really that slow than PDO?

Tags: php, doctrine, pdo, doctrine-orm

I have recently learned about PDO and and Doctrine 2.2.2 to build an application.
but i'will work with  some critical constraints in my environment( a lot of data , connexion speed ...etc)
i know that Doctrine have a PDO layer,so maybe PDO is faster but i want to work with a Real ORM Framework like Hibernate.

after reading this post
 [Benchmark PDO vs Doctrine](http://vincent-lecomte.blogspot.com/2011/01/web-php-zend-benchmark-pdo-vs-doctrine.html)

I have to know if Doctrine is [ very ] slow than PDO.

Thank you

Comment: Comparing PDO with Doctrine is like comparing apples with apple trees. Also note, that Doctrine2 is faster

Comment: you are right , i know what you mean ; but i just need to know how much Doctrine is slow.
thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Doctrine 2 + PHP 5.3+ improved greatly the speed of Doctrine.

However, you will never be close to PDO beacause **it is not the same thing** : do you want to query your database or do you want to automatically map your database to PHP Objects and then use objects in your code ?

- For development quality, ease and speed : use Doctrine
- For runtime speed : don't use an ORM

Comment: Thanks a lot ..i think i going to use doctrine 2

Comment: After working on at-least 3 to 4 projects. I experienced that PDO is much much faster. For UX perspective I always choose PDO over ORM. You can always write neat and understandable code with normal SQL queries using DBAL layer.

Answer (score 10):

Using a PHP cache like APC will improve Doctrine's performance a lot. From what I've seen; somewhere between 3-7 times.
If you can't use a cache, you could easily switch to Doctrine's DBAL layer instead of the ORM in areas where you really need all the speed you can get. Runtime speeds will then be a lot closer to PDO, but you will lose the convenience of an ORM.